# iOS: stripe checkout UI embedded in UIViewController

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

In the attached screenshots from https://stripe.com/checkout , Stripe makes it look like you can embed the Stripe checkout UI in a view controller, but I can't find the drop in UI for that anywhere for iOS, they only provide javascript implementation. Does anyone know where I can get the iOS implementation?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) is a JavaScript library that you can embed into a web application, or into a mobile app via a webview.

Stripe also has an [iOS SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) that includes a pre-built component to collect card information ([`STPPaymentCardTextField`](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#prebuilt)), but it's different than Checkout.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to avoid the webview and actually embed it in a view controller - but if it's not possible it's not possible i guess. Yeah I tried setting that STPPaymentCardTextField but it wasn't appearing on the VC for some reason. What does it do/why should i use it if it's just a textfield?